# How to Detach Firestore SnapshotListener in Repository (MVVM)

Tags: kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, listener, android-livedata, android-mvvm

I believe I need to detach Firestore listeners but I can't see how to do this without passing the context to my repository.  Below is one example:

**Fragment**

This method is called in `onViewCreated` and simply updates `private var sitesList = ArrayList<SiteObject>()` which is used to set list in my recyclerview:

```js
    private fun setupObservers() {
        Log.d(TAG, "setupObservers()")
        businessViewModel.listenToSites().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { allSites ->
            if (sitesList != allSites && allSites != null) {
                sitesList.clear()
                sitesList.addAll(allSites)
                sitesAdapter.setList(sitesList)
                sitesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
        })
    }
```

**ViewModel**

```js
    fun listenToSites(): LiveData<ArrayList<SiteObject>> {
        Log.d(TAG, "listenToSites()")
        return businessRepository.listenToSites()
    }
```

**Repository**

This is where the Firestore `addSnapshotListener` is created:

```js
  fun listenToSites(): LiveData<ArrayList<SiteObject>> {

        Log.d(TAG, "listenToSites(), firebaseUser = ${firebaseUser?.uid}")
        val userId = firebaseUser?.uid

        firestore.collection(SITES).whereEqualTo("users.${userId}", true)
            .addSnapshotListener(MetadataChanges.INCLUDE, EventListener { snapshots, e ->
                if (e != null) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "listenToSites(), listen error:", e)
                    return@EventListener
                }
                val allSites = ArrayList<SiteObject>()
                if (snapshots != null) {
                    for (document in snapshots) {
                        val site = document.toObject(SiteObject::class.java)
                        site.siteID = document.id
                        allSites.add(site)
                    }

                    for (docChange in snapshots.documentChanges) {
                        when (docChange) {
                            DocumentChange.Type.ADDED -> Log.d(TAG, "New site: ${docChange.document.data}")
                            DocumentChange.Type.MODIFIED -> Log.d(TAG, "Modified site: ${docChange.document.data}")
                            DocumentChange.Type.REMOVED -> Log.d(TAG, "Removed site: ${docChange.document.data}")
                        }
                    }

                    val source = if (snapshots.metadata.isFromCache){
                        "local cache"
                    }
                    else {
                        "server"
                    }
                    Log.d(TAG, "Sites data fetched from $source")
                }
                sitesMutableLiveData.value = allSites

            })

        return sitesMutableLiveData
    }
```

So I guess I could pass the Fragment context by passing it up the chain as an argument like this:

```
businessViewModel.listenToSites(context)
```

Passing this through the VM, Repository to the snapshotListener as below:

```
addSnapshotListener(context, MetadataChanges.INCLUDE, EventListener....
```

But was unsure if this is the recommended way to do it or how best to capture the context in the Fragment?

Quick bonus question out of interest; does the `snapshots.documentChanges` code create additional listeners?  I'm just using while I debug, but thought it could..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your repository layer should never include a single line of Android-related code. Your ViewModel is a common ground for the Android and the repo layer code. You can make ViewModel lifecycle aware by implementing `LifeCycleObserver` interface.

```
class YourViewModel : LifeCycleObserver {

  @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP) //Annotate it with any lifecycle event of your choice.
  fun aMethodThatRemovesObserver() {
      //Invoked on onStop()
  }

}
```

In your activity:

```
onCreate() {
   lifecycle.addObserver(yourViewModel)
}
```

No need to worry about removing ViewModel observer manually, it will be gone in `uncleared` state of your ViewModel. Just keep in mind that the repository layer should remain free of Android-related code. If you need a context, you can use `AndroidViewModel` (scoped to application). Sometimes it's not possible to seperate out context, in that case, I would just provide it with an applicationContext but not an Activity context.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response - is it actually good practice to detach Firestore listeners this way? i.e. will they remain unless you detach (with potential for duplication of listeners)?

Comment: I am not sure if it is universally considered a best practice, but it is surely better than letting the activity control add/remove listeners that it is not supposed to know. By doing this, the activity only knows the interfaces it can use and benefit from.